# Inserting a User through ActionController using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I am trying to add a new `User` in my database, but every time I press **submit** i get this error

> HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. "

This is my controller:

```
public class CreateController : Controller
{
    // GET: Create
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(User user)
    {
        using (var db = new UserEntities())
        {
            User newUser = new User();
            newUser.Name = user.Name;
            db.Users.Add(newUser);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my view:

```
@model FormulörModul.Models.User

<title>Create</title>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "CreateController", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <label>Namn</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is in the call to `Html.BeginForm`. By convention in MVC, when you name a controller you just name the string before "Controller". I.e. replace this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "CreateController", FormMethod.Post))
```

with this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Create", FormMethod.Post))
```

BTW, "Create" is a really bad name for a controller. I would name it "User".

Comment: Thank you so much, that was indeed the problem! And yes i'll keep that in mind! I kidna just threw together something fast which resembled an exercise i had in school, and its 5am atm ha!

Comment: @user1612725 glad I could help!

Comment: Think of Controller names as nouns, and what you want to do as (verbs) as actions/methods.  `UserController.Create()`.